# What is the difference between XSS and Cross Site Flashing?

Tags: xss, exploit, flash, defense

I want to know the basic differences between XSS and XSF

Answer (score 3):

XSF is, essentially, XSS in a Flash applet. Where in XSS you find vectors (e.g. URL parameters or form fields) for injecting content into the DOM that is parsed as script, in XSF you look for cases where you can get untrusted data to be placed into Flash variables, which may then be used in an unescaped context inside the Flash applet, resulting in script execution, open redirect, or other impacts.